# Add X rows to datatable that are virtually the same?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, datatable

Let's say I need to add 10 rows to my datatable that are virtually the same, except for one value. So, for example, I use the following code to add the first row:

```
row = myTable.NewRow();
row["col1"] = value1;
row["col2"] = value2;
row["col3"] = value3;
row["col4"] = value4;
row["col5"] = value5;
row["col6"] = value6;
myTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

The next 9 rows are exactly the same, the only difference being "col4", since "value4" is different in all 10 rows.

How would I be able to insert this same row X times without having to duplicate the previous code? Basically, it would be:

1. Create Row1
2. fill Row1 with values
3. Copy Row1 to new Row2
4. Change Row2["col4"]
5. Add both rows to myTable

Thanks.

Comment: Where you get values for col4? Is it some array of values?

Comment: No. It's a string created based on the row. The first row would have one value, the 2nd row another value, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pattern similar to the following, you would just pass in your array of values as a parameter and get back a populated table:

```
    private DataTable CreateRows(object[] column4Vals)
    {
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (object col in column4Vals)
        {
            DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
            row["col1"] = "value1";
            row["col2"] = "value2";
            row["col3"] = "value3";
            row["col4"] = col;
            row["col5"] = "value5";
            row["col6"] = "value6";
            myTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return myTable;
    }
```

Here is also a more flexible way so you can assign any other values for your standard data.

```
    private DataTable CreateRows(object value1, object value2, object value3, object[] column4Vals, object value5, object value6)
    {
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (object col in column4Vals)
        {
            DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
            row["col1"] = value1;
            row["col2"] = value2;
            row["col3"] = value3;
            row["col4"] = col;
            row["col5"] = value5;
            row["col6"] = value6;
            myTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return myTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple loop will do the job. You also can use overloaded [DataRowCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56(v=vs.110).aspx) method which accepts array of values that are used to create new row:

```
// e.g. you have 10 integers for col4
var col4values = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

foreach(var col4value in col4values)
  myTable.Rows.Add(value1, value2, value3, col4value, value5, value6);
```

Comment: I was hoping to declare a `DataRow row` so that I can set the values by column name. The datatable has 17 fields.

Comment: @user3605366 when you pass column values, new row is created and added internally

Comment: Just beware for presence of autoincrement column and missing columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should be very careful in doing this using 'DataRow'. Typically you add a reference to a row to the table, and change the referenced row, instead of adding a new row.

You could however duplicate the datarow first, before adding it to the table.

Look into:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow(v=vs.110).aspx

for a better explanation and example.